# How to disable ESLint react/prop-types rule in a file?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using `React` and `ESLint` with `eslint-plugin-react`.

I want to `disable` the `prop-types` rule in one file.

```js
var React = require('react'); 
var Model = require('./ComponentModel');

var Component = React.createClass({
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
    propTypes: Model.propTypes,
/* eslint-enable react/prop-types */
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="component">
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file)

Comment: ESLint has nothing to do with your code being react or whatnot.  I have provided a detailed answer of all the cases (single/multiple line/file, some/all rules) in this *answer*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just put this on top of your file:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
```

Comment: Tried it out and it works fine. It's a cleaner approach. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `0`, I'd recommend putting `off`. When working with many developers of different skill levels, it's best to be explicit rather than requiring they know `0` stands for `off`.

Answer (score 264):

if you have only one file you want to disable prop-type validation you can use:

```
/* eslint react/prop-types: 0 */
```

in cases where you have multiple files you can add to your `.eslintrc` file in your root directory a rule to disable prop-type validation:

```
{
 "plugins": [
     "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0
  }
}
```

for further rules you can checkout [this link](https://c9.io/burnnat/eslint-plugin-react) that solved my issue and for your convenience you can also read up from [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md)'s github documentation about how to disable or enable it with various options.

Comment: `"react/prop-types": "off"` also works (and it is a little more readable)

Comment: Fro me, it works: 'react/prop-types': false

Answer (score 37):

I had to do:

```
/* eslint react/forbid-prop-types: 0 */
```

this did **not** work for me:

```
/* eslint react/prop-types: 0 */
```

To disable globally in your .eslintrc file (old version v6.0 or below):

```
{
    "rules": {
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 0
    }
}
```

To disable globally in your .eslintrc file (new version above v6.0):

```
{
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: The part about rules is incorrect as of 2020. Use

 `    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 0
    }
`

Answer (score 9):

I had to wrap the whole component with the eslint ignore comments.

```
var React = require('react'); 
var Model = require('./ComponentModel');

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
var Component = React.createClass({

    propTypes: Model.propTypes,

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="component">
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
/* eslint-enable react/prop-types */
```

Comment: My hero. This solved why I wasn't able to get `/* eslint-disable react/no-multi-comp */` when just wrapping my first component in it.

Comment: `/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */` should be placed at the very beginning of a file

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I have small components in the same file as the major one. There propTypes seems overkill. Then I usually do something like this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const RightArrow = ({ onPress, to }) => (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(to)} style={styles.rightArrow}><Chevrons.chevronRight size={25} color="grey" /></TouchableOpacity>);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to do this in my `.eslintrc` config file to disable prop types validation error.

```
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable or modify the react/prop-types rule in your `.eslint.cjs` file, you can use the following configurations:

Option 1: Disable the rule completely

```
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": "off"
}
```

or

```
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": 0
}
```

or

```
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": false
}
```

Option 2: Set the rule to generate warnings instead of errors

```
"rules": {
  "react/prop-types": ["warn"]
}
```

Choose the option that best suits your requirements and add it to your `.eslint.cjs` file. This will configure ESLint to either disable the react/prop-types rule or modify its severity to generate warnings instead of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I needed React relaunch for this to be taken into account without error

```
rules: {
  'react/prop-types': 'off'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to be warning, put it inside `eslint` rules:

`'react/prop-types': ['warn'],`

Answer (score 0):

Best is to add this line :

```
'react/prop-types':[disabled] //* disabling eslint prop-types all warnings
```

add this line to your **module.exports** object in **.eslintrc.cjs** in file.

Comment: OP asked how to disable the rule for just one file.