# Turning off eslint rule for a specific file

Tags: configuration, eslint, lint

Is it possible to turn off the eslint rule for the whole file? Something such as:

```
// eslint-disable-file no-use-before-define
```

(Analogous to eslint-disable-line.) It happens to me quite often, that in a certain file, I'm breaking a specific rule on many places which is considered OK for that file, but I don't want to disable the rule for the whole project nor do I want to disable other rules for that specific file.

Comment: You can add a rule as the first line of the file as so: /*eslint no-use-before-define: 2*/

Comment: perfect, that works, thank you. I just overlooked the section in the docs: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

Comment: So many duplicated answers in here.. If a mod could delete all the `/* eslint-disable */` answers except the first one that would be nice

Comment: for future readers, if you're also using prettier and eslint-disable isn't working you should create a .prettierignore file and add the file in question to that file, none of the eslint comments in this thread worked for me because of prettier

Answer (score 619, accepted):

You can turn off/change a particular rule for a file by putting the configurations at the top of the file.

```
/* eslint no-use-before-define: 0 */  // --> OFF

or

/* eslint no-use-before-define: 2 */  // --> ON
```

[More info](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules)

Comment: Is there a way to put a rule in `.eslintrc` that enforces all **file specific** rules like this to the top of the file?

Comment: @Jeremy see my answer. You just need to add an `.eslintignore` file to your project root directory.

Comment: Nice! Saw some JSON-y answers floating around that didn't seem to work for disabling no-camelcase errors, but this (`/* eslint camelcase: 0 */`) did the trick (using eslint via standard.js)

Comment: I tried /* eslint-disable rule-name */ and it worked

Comment: :1 makes it a Warning instead of Error

Comment: The double comment formatting in this answer mislead me.

Comment: You can also set env values in a file: `/*eslint-env node */`

Comment: @Jeremy Yes. I designed a way to remove specific rules from specific files or folders. Please check my answer right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069069/7644846

@prograhammer Putting the file on `.eslintignore` will disable ALL rules from the files. But @Jeremy want to disable specific rules from files.

Comment: I upvoted this answer for answering correctly. However, if we want to disable a specific rule from a lot of different files, we need to add the `/* eslint no-use-before-define: 0 */` on *173* different files for example. You can just change in just one file: `.eslintrc` using the `overrides`. I explained more about this on my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069069/7644846

Comment: Using `off` now also works: `/* eslint no-use-before-define: off */`

Comment: `/* eslint no-use-before-define: 2 */`  can make the rule more strict. For example from 'warn' to 'error' level

It's better to use `/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */` and later `/* eslint-enable no-use-before-define */`

Comment: @Jeremy keep scrolling to find my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951 for disabling specific file/rules.

Answer (score 556):

To disable a specific rule for the file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
```

Note there is a bug in eslint where single line comment will not work -

```
// eslint-disable max-classes-per-file
// This fails!
```

[Check this post](https://evanhahn.com/disable-eslint-for-a-file/)

Comment: This will disable all eslint rules within that block, not just the one `no-use-before-define` intended to ignore

Comment: Basically that is the whole idea. The question is "Is it possible to turn off the eslint rule for the **whole file**? "

Comment: @Wahome "Is it possible to turn off the eslint **rule** for the whole file?" The word rule is *singular*. Your answer turns off all *rules* plural.

Comment: in the description he mentioned that he wants soemthing like disabling specific rule- read again the question!

Comment: It's true, this doesn't address the whole question, but still a useful answer since this thread is a top result when googling "eslint ignore file"

Comment: Just append the rule(s) at the end `/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */`

Comment: The `/*` and `*/`, apparently, matter (`//` didn't work).

Comment: See my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951) if you want to have more granular control on which files/lines/rules to ignore.

Comment: For anyone else confused by the comments, `/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */` is definitely a correct answer which disables a *specific* rule for the whole file. Notice the edits in the answer. The comments were directed at the original answer which was "Just place /* eslint-disable */ at the top of the file."

Answer (score 417):

Let's have a breakdown of the scenarios, like you always do, dear awesome developer!

Here are two questions to ask yourself, first.

#### Question One: How many "rules" do you want to ignore?

1. **All Rules**
2. One or more **Specific Rules** (e.g. `quotes` or `semi`)

#### Question Two: How many "lines/files" do you want to ignore?

1. One or more **Lines**
2. All lines in one or more **Files**
3. **Everywhere**

Now, based on the your answers, there are 2 × 3 = 6 cases.

---

### 1) Disabling "All rules"

---

**Case 1.1: You want to disable "All Rules" for "One or more Lines"**

Two ways you can do this:

1. Put `/* eslint-disable-line */` at the **end of the line(s)**,
2. or `/* eslint-disable-next-line */` right **before the line**.

---

**Case 1.2: You want to disable "All Rules" for "One File"**

- Put the comment of `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of the file.

---

**Case 1.3: You want to disable "All rules" for "Some Files"**

There are 3 ways you can do this:

1. You can go with 1.2 and add `/* eslint-disable */` on top of the files, one by one.
2. You can put the file name(s) in `.eslintignore`. This works well, especially if you have a *path* that you want to be ignored. (e.g. `apidoc/**`)
3. Alternatively, if you don't want to have a separate `.eslintignore` file, you can add
   `"eslintIgnore": ["file1.js", "file2.js"]` in `package.json` as
   instructed [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#using-eslintignore-in-packagejson).

---

### 2) Disabling "Some Rules"

---

**Case 2.1: You want to disable "Some Rules" for "One or more Lines"**

Two ways you can do this:

1. You can put `/* eslint-disable-line quotes */` (replace `quotes` with your rules) at the end of the line(s),
2. or `/* eslint-disable-next-line no-alert, quotes, semi */` before the line.

Pro Tip: if you have multiple lines that you want to ignore the same rule(s) for, you can disable and enable the rules like this:

```js
// Assume these lines are long engouh that max-len is gonna trigger

/* eslint-disable max-len */
console.log("I am a loooooooooo...ooooong line 1, but eslint doesn't bug!");
console.log("I am a loooooooooo...ooooong line 2, but eslint doesn't bug!");
console.log("I am a loooooooooo...ooooong line 3, but eslint doesn't bug!");
/* eslint-enable max-len */
console.log("I am a loooooooooo...ooooong line 4, AND eslint's GONNA CRY!"); // <--- eslint is gonna cry over this one only!
```

---

**Case 2.2: You want to disable "Some Rules" for "One File"**

- Put the `/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */` comment at the top of the file.

More examples [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules).

---

**Case 2.3: You want to disable "Some Rules" for "Some files"**

- This is less straightforward.  You should create an `"overrides"` section in your `.eslintrc` and specify which rules should be disabled/modified for which globs/files.  An example can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069069).

Comment: PS. Case 5: You want to disable "All rules" for "All Files" -- `npm uninstall eslint`! :p

Comment: Also note that you can only use `/* */` style comment for `eslint-disable`.  `// eslint-disable no-use-before-define` is not gonna work.  

It works for `// eslint-disable-next-line` though.

Comment: I was needing exactly the **Case 2.3** during the time I was reading your comment and it is not completely explained on your answer. For anyone who want to know the **Case 2.3**, it is fully explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069069/7644846 . PS: `"excludedFiles"` doesn't work if you want to disable specific rules for specific files.

Comment: Thanks @victor for bringing it to my attention.  It seems like eslint documentation links had changed.  I updated them, and also made a reference to your answer for 2.3. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 246):

You can tell ESLint to [ignore specific files and directories](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#ignoring-files-and-directories) by creating an `.eslintignore` file in your project’s root directory:

**.eslintignore**

```
build/*.js
config/*.js
bower_components/foo/*.js
```

The ignore patterns behave according to the `.gitignore` specification.
(Don't forget to restart your editor.)

Comment: Is it possible to ignore only specific rules in this file?

Comment: Very nice! You can also add files in directories, subdirectories, subsubdirectories in a recursive way using **. For example: `spec/javascripts/**/*.js`.

Comment: Perfect - This is particularly useful for files that are auto-generated and changed frequently (like aws-exports.js if you're using AWS's Amplify or MobileHub)

Comment: This still gives a warning

Comment: @dan-klasson That's incorrect. I've used this approach for years. Unless you are referring to the case where you explicitly pass a file into the eslint command and it warns you that you ignored this. But most all cases are where you specify a directory such as `eslint .` or `eslint src/`. You will NOT see warnings for ignored files that way.

Comment: It's also confirmed here in their documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#ignored-file-warnings `When you pass directories to ESLint, files and directories are silently ignored. If you pass a specific file to ESLint, then you will see a warning indicating that the file was skipped.`

Comment: It's a git commit hook. I don't know how it's run. But I did get a warning.

Comment: be careful about running eslint with `--ignore-path` argument. it would bypasses `.eslintignore` file content.

Comment: This answer disable **all** rules from those files. In order to remove **specifics** rules from files, you ca check on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069069/7644846

Comment: @J.Hesters Yes! It is possible to remove **specific** rules from files by using the `"overrides"` key. You can check that on my answer right here: stackoverflow.com/a/65069069/7644846

Comment: `*.min.*` will ignore minified files

Comment: @J.Hesters keep scrolling to find my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951 for disabling specific file(s) and/or rule(s).

Answer (score 135):

You can also disable/enable a rule like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
... code that violates rule ...
/* eslint-enable no-use-before-define */
```

Similar to `eslint-disable-line` as mentioned in the question. It might be a better method if you don't want to have to restore a complicated rule configuration when re-enabling it.

Comment: I Prefer this one, because it restores the level (warn, error) that I have defined in my eslint config.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Turning the rule off and on didn't work.

Comment: The problem with having this pattern in your codebase is, future developers who come to do this on their own files will forget re-enabling it.  (It's not easy to see the difference when you don't re-enable.)  That's why I personally prefer mostly `// esint-disable-line` or `/* eslint-disable-next-line */` which is for one line only. Find them with more details at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951/2321594

Answer (score 127):

It's better to add "overrides" in your .eslintrc.js config file.
For example if you wont to disable camelcase rule for all js files ending on Actions add this code after rules scope in .eslintrc.js.

```
"rules": {    
...........    
},
"overrides": [
 {
  "files": ["*Actions.js"],
     "rules": {
        "camelcase": "off"   
     }
 }
]
```

Comment: It does not answer OP's question about specific file.

Comment: Works great! IMHO this should be the accepted answer.  This way stays in eslintrc file (keeps source files clean) and can override behavior of specific rules for specific files. +1

Comment: Works well for a `*.d.ts` file so that you can stop linting warnings on type definitions for things like `no-unused-vars` or `max-classes-per-file` or `no-use-before-define`

Comment: @akagixxer but you don't have control over one instance (i.e. line) with this method.  OTOH, putting it in the code itself makes more visible to everyone that you are doing a "bad" thing, but an exception is justified.  Also, my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951 contains different ways that you can do it.

Comment: ignoring lint rules in the source code in practice just provides patterns for developers in the future to ignore rules, and inevitably, legitimate rules get ignored. 

+1 for using overrides for legitimate exceptions to your ruleset
+1 for this being the accepted answer

Answer (score 77):

To disable specific rules for file(s) inside folder(s), you need to use the `"overrides"` key of your `.eslintrc` config file.

For example, if you want to remove the following rules:

1. `no-use-before-define`
2. `max-lines-per-function`

For all files inside the following main directory:

`/spec`

You can add this to your `.eslintrc` file...

```js
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["spec/**/*.js"],
    "rules": {
      "no-use-before-define": ["off"],
      "max-lines-per-function": ["off"]
    }
  }
]
```

Note that I used `**` inside the `spec/**/*.js` [**glob**](https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial), which means I am looking recursively for all **subfolders** inside the **folder** called `spec` and selecting all files that ends with `js` in order to remove the desired rules from them.

Comment: IMO this approach is gonna make it harder to maintain.  The future developer who wants to know why a certain rule is disabled, has to look in so many places.  It might be easier to either centralize the rule-overrides in one place (one `.eslintrc`/`.eslintignore`) or do it per line/file, or both.

Comment: I didn't understand your concern because this approach is exactly centralizing the rule-override inside one place: the `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: I see.  I was under the impression that you are talking putting multiple `.eslintrc` files in different folders. My bad. :)

Comment: This approach is far better than using comments. Code should never contain info about external things related to the build process.

Answer (score 71):

To temporarily disable rule warnings in your file, use block comments in the following format:

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

This will disable ESLint until the

```
/* eslint-enable */
```

comment is reached.

You can read more about this topic [here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments).

Answer (score 37):

Accepted answer didn't work for me (maybe a different version of eslint...? I'm using `eslint v3.19.0`), but did find a solution with the following...

Place the following on the top of your file

`/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */`

This will disable the rule for the entire file

Comment: ...or multiple, like `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars, no-console, import/no-extraneous-dependencies, spaced-comment */`

Comment: same same, accepted answer didn't work for me. Two differences: changing `eslint` to `eslint-disable` and dropping `: 0`. Using eslint@4.19.1.

Answer (score 33):

```
/* eslint-disable */

//suppress all warnings between comments
alert('foo');

/* eslint-enable */
```

This will disable all eslint rules within the block.

Comment: This will disable all eslint rules within that block, not just the one `no-use-before-define` intended to ignore

Comment: This helped me, thanks! Also consider this answer the question, disabling all rules also disable the intended rule

Comment: Really not a good practice.  Just because you want to do one "unorthodox" thing, shouldn't justify a total chaos. :)  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951 for more granularity.

Answer (score 17):

Simple and effective.

Eslint 6.7.0 brought "ignorePatterns" to write it in .eslintrc.json like this example:

```
{
    "ignorePatterns": ["fileToBeIgnored.js"],
    "rules": {
        //...
    }
}
```

[See docs](https://eslint.org/docs/6.0.0/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)

Comment: Note that it ignores "ALL" the rules for the "ENTIRE" file.  If you want more granularity, check my an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951

Answer (score 17):

If you want to disable ESLint for one rule, you can add this to the top of the file:

```js
/* eslint-disable NAME_OF_THE_RULE */
```

If you want to disable ESLint or TypeScript checks inside a file, you can add these lines at the top of the file. The first one will disable TypeScript checks, and the second one ESLint checks.

```js
// @ts-nocheck
/* eslint-disable */
```

Answer (score 15):

Just add this to the top of your file.
This disables all eslint warnings respectively.

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

Comment: > nor do I want to disable other rules for that specific file

Answer (score 9):

you can configure eslint overrides property to turn off specific rules on files which matches glob pattern like below.

Here, I want to turn off the `no-duplicate-string` rule for tests all files.

```js
overrides: [
  {
    files: ["**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
    rules: {
      'sonarjs/no-duplicate-string': 'off'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Was looking exactly for this! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can just put this for example at the top of the file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
```

Answer (score 7):

As of today, the answer does not work for me, but putting this at the top of the file **does work**:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```

It is important to know that at least in my case, the type of comment makes a difference. The previous comment works for me, but the following **won't work**:

```js
// eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Comment: so true. still same in 2023 :D

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off specific rule for a file by using `/*eslint [<rule: "off"], >]*/`

`/* eslint no-console: "off", no-mixed-operators: "off" */`

Version: `eslint@4.3.0`

Comment: This worked perfectly fine in case one needs to disable one rule only for one complete file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an empty file `.eslintignore` in your project root the type the path to the file you want it to be ignore.

Source: [https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#:~:text=To%20disable%20rule%20warnings%20in,*%2F%20alert('foo')%3B](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20rule%20warnings%20in,*%2F%20alert(%27foo%27)%3B)

Line **Ignoring Files and Directories**

Comment: You will not have control over specific rules with this, neither specific lines. My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951 covers more cases, based on the need.

Comment: I appreciate this was in case you want to ignore warnings in a specific file

Answer (score -1):

To temporarily disable rule warnings in your file, use block comments in the following format:

/* eslint-disable */

alert('foo');

/* eslint-enable */
You can also disable or enable warnings for specific rules:

/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */

alert('foo');
console.log('bar');

/* eslint-enable no-alert, no-console */
To disable rule warnings in an entire file, put a /* eslint-disable */ block comment at the top of the file:

/* eslint-disable */

alert('foo');
You can also disable or enable specific rules for an entire file:

/* eslint-disable no-alert */

alert('foo');
To disable all rules on a specific line, use a line comment in one of the following formats:

Following are some examples to disable ESLint for a page

alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line

// eslint-disable-next-line
alert('foo');
To disable a specific rule on a specific line:

alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line no-alert

// eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
alert('foo');
To disable multiple rules on a specific line:

alert('foo'); // eslint-disable-line no-alert, quotes, semi

// eslint-disable-next-line no-alert, quotes, semi
alert('foo');

---

Do following steps to disable ESLint from your project

- open package.config file in your project.
- remove all dependencies related to ESLint.
- remove eslint.js/eslintconfig files from your project
- run command npm install
- now run your project

Comment: The original post asked how to disable it for a _single_ file. Not the entire project.

Comment: You can use one backtick (the character next to 1) to format one span, or triple-backtick to format one block.  See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Spending a few minutes formatting your answer can be more helpful and also have higher chance of receiving upvotes. :)