# How to disable all checking for given file(s)?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have some vendored JS libraries in a project, and I want to disable all ESLint checking for these files.

I've looked at the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/user-guide/configuring) and it describes how to disable checking via inline comments, e.g.

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

..but I would rather not touch the files, and configure ESLint via e.g. a local `.eslintrc` file. How to disable all checking as above, via such a file, is not described in the documentation.

Is it possible, and if so what would the `.eslintrc` file look like? It would be OK to disable *all* checking in a given directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file)

Comment: No, the accepted answer in that question did not help as it specifically suggests the approach I said I couldn't use, but my question here was answered correctly and accepted back in 2017, so no worries.

Comment: Nobody said anything about the _accepted_ answer, pages scroll.

Comment: But I already had an accepted and correct answer. Why go to a completely different place and have to scroll around looking for what you might have been referring to?

Comment: As you say, you already got your answer (which also did say at the time that they'd just taken it from an existing post, so you already knew it was a dupe, but whatever). I'm not adding the duplicate for you, I'm adding it for the next person who wants to disable ESLint rules but can't read the manual, so they end up at the canonical post.

Comment: That post you refer to is in no way canonical or a duplicate for my question that is asking how to disable for a file *without* editing in the file itself.  The other post is literally asking for the syntax for a rule *within the file* to disable a rule in that file - as the accepted answer for their question indeed does. It is very irritating to post on SO and getting a wrong "duplicate" assumption. Please read the questions more carefully, as I assume this is not the only one you have been editing.

Comment: The point of the duplicate system is to get people to the _answers_. The answers there show various options for disabling rules, including for a whole project - as you were _already told_ in the answer here (which should probably have been a dupe suggestion to start with). _"as I assume this is not the only one you have been editing"_ - you don't have to assume anything, it's a matter of [public record](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: I disagree. A duplicate is a post that asks the same question. Not a post where one of the non-accepted answers further down the page just happens to answer the same question. And sarcastic comments like "pages scroll" don't help.  I'd appreciate it if you removed the link you added to my accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: I didn't add the link. You can see from the post history: 1. exactly what I _did_ change; and 2. that the link to the dupe was there in the very first revision (and then automatically rewritten to HTTPS later that year) - which is why I say it was obvious _at the time_. Also see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294704/248731

Comment: OK, the link wasn't yours - I see also that MP called it a "similar" question. You're still calling it a dupe, which is bizarre. To someone using SO the property of being a duplicate is a property of the question, not whether there exists an off-topic answer. If applied everywhere it would make it really difficult to search to see if a question had already been answered. You will note I worded my question specifically to exclude the case covered by that other question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110360/4259027) answer from a similar question.

Basically you should add a `.eslintignore` file to your project's root directory and specify the files and directories you want to ignore like so:

`.eslintignore` file:

```
build/*.js
config/*.js
bower_components/foo/*.js
```

Also look at [this](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore) section from the official ESLint docs