# Allow debugger; statements in certain files, using ESLint

Tags: eslint, eslintignore, eslintrc

Say I want to use this rule:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-debugger

however, I have about 15 files where I want to keep debugger; statements.

Is there something I can add at the top of the .ts/.js files, that can tell ESLint to ignore the `no-debugger` rule for this particular file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file)

Answer (score 89):

You can also disable ESLint in the same line:

```
debugger; // eslint-disable-line no-debugger
```

Comment: I had to do it for ```console.debug``` and ```console.error``` and I used this: ```// eslint-disable-next-line no-console``` on the line above the statements.

Answer (score 25):

You can do that like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-debugger */
... code that violates rule ...
/* eslint-enable no-debugger */
```

Answer (score 16):

Update your eslint configuration file (`.eslintrc` etc) with such rule:

```
"rules": {
    "no-debugger":"off"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would resolve the question?

Comment: Tried using this and got 

```  Configuration for rule "no-debugger" is invalid:
        Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed 'false').```

Answer (score 9):

Probably your IDE can help. If you are using VS Code, you can mouse over `debugger`, click `Quick Fix...`, and select `Disable no-debugger for the entire file`, as shown as below:

[image]

Then the IDE will add the following comment at the top of the file to disable the rule for you:

```
/* eslint-disable no-debugger */
```

See more on [the eslint no-debugger rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-debugger).

Answer (score 2):

OR, add:

```
"no-debugger": false
```

to the bottom of tslint.json, to disable this warning for all files.

Answer (score 0):

I think `debugger` need to removed, and briefly used in a development environment.

So you're better off ignoring it where you use.

For example:
disable no-debugger for this line

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    debugger
```

or disable no-debugger for the entire file

```
/* eslint-disable no-debugger */
```