# Debugger statement throws an error in vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a simple **v-on:click="demo"** method that is attached to my input. In my **demo** function I use **debugger** statement to stop JavaScript engine execution. The problem is that **debugger** statement throws none sense errors in **es-lint** module. My question is simple. How to make debugger work ?

**Code**

```
export default {
  name: "Demo",
  methods: {
    demo: function () {
      console.log('Running demo')
      debugger
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Demo.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/app/src/components/Upload.vue
   2:1   warning  Insert `··`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      prettier/prettier
   3:1   warning  Insert `··`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      prettier/prettier
   ...
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, ES-linter disallows **debugger** statement [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-debugger). To make debugger work again I had to add `// eslint-disable-line` comment to my debugger line. Below lines of code solved the debugger error.

```
debugger // eslint-disable-line
```

or

```
/* eslint-disable no-debugger */
debugger
```

Comment: How can we change this in the linter config?

Comment: ok, so you add this rule to packages.json "rules" section. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423266/allow-debugger-statements-in-certain-files-using-eslint

Comment: No. I just write these rules (comments) in my js code.