# eslint - enable es5 syntax only for a single file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Excerpt from my `.eslintrc`:

```
env: {
    es6: true
}
```

Most files use es6 because they are passed through the Babel transpiler. However, some files are not. For those few can I get eslint to allow es5 syntax only?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file

Comment: no, thats disabling a rule for a file - this is changing an "env" setting for a file.

Comment: @kaushik94: No, `env` isn't a rule. There is [`eslint-dev`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments), but it doesn't document turning an env *off* (`/* eslint-dev: no-es6 */` or similar), just turning an env *on*. danday74: You might try that, though, or variations on it (or read the source). And if it doesn't work, fork eslint, add the feature, and do a pull request. :-)

Comment: Would you like to enforce only es5 rules for these files? Like a split eslint setup?