# How to disable vue/multi-word-component-names eslint rule for just one .vue file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, eslint, eslintrc

I am using the [Vue ESLint plugin](https://eslint.vuejs.org/) and it has a rule for [not allowing single word component names.](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html)

However, I am also using Nuxt, and to [set a default Layout](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts#default-layout) in Nuxt you need a .vue component named `default.vue` which throws the ES Lint rule errors.

I can't seem to get it to just disable in that one .vue file that is actually pretty small...

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Header/>
        <Nuxt/>
    </div>
</template>
```

But if I disable the rule in my `.eslintrc.js` then it works.

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  plugins: [],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
  },
}
```

Is there a way to disable the rule for just one Vue file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file)

Comment: FWIW, this rule is totally impractical and could be disabled forever.

Comment: This is marked as essential here: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential

Answer (score 48):

In your case, you can replace

```
'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off'
```

with:

```
'vue/multi-word-component-names': ['error', {
  'ignores': ['default']
}]
```

this will set the rule to 'allow' for all files named 'default'

you can read more about it here: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Comment: I get the error ``Definition for rule ' vue/no-reserved-component-names' was not found   vue/no-reserved-component-names``.

Comment: where to find it ?

Answer (score 29):

`rules: { 'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0 }`
try this way

Comment: Isn't this functionally equivalent to the existing answer?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Same as which one? It's 0 not off

Comment: This working for me. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. The anwer above from Ahmad Ibrahim did not work

Answer (score 14):

Go to **package.json** and in the **eslintConfig** object add the following rule: `"vue/multi-word-component-names": "off"`

or even better:
`"vue/multi-word-component-names": 0`

### Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can override the rule to apply only for the specific files.

Here's the `.eslintrc.js` configuration

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  plugins: [],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['src/components/default.vue'],  // Change this to default.vue path
      rules: {
        'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have eslintConfig in package.json.

You need just set vue/multi-word-component-names to 0

rules: {
'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Command `npm install standardx --global`.
2. In `vue.config.js`, add `lintOnSave:false`.
3. In App.vue inside template, add div as parent element and wrap your image and component that you are using in that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two ways to actually resolve this problem.

1 Use CamelCase minimum two words to for Component Name.

```
export default {
name: "HeaderComponent" // Header to HeaderComponent
}
```

2 Add the following code to the `package.json:eslintConfig.rules` to disable this rule.

```
"vue/multi-word-component-names": 0
```

3 Remove the eslint package from node_modules.

```
$ npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above for a component named "Header.vue", but none of them worked. I finally added a comment to disable the rule in eslint, like so,

From:

```
<script lang="js">
    export default {        
        name: 'Header',
    };
</script>
```

To:

```
<script lang="js">
    export default {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        name: 'Header',
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just the below line the `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ....
  lintOnSave: false
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace `vue.config.js`
with:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  lintOnSave: false,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the vue.config.js file
2. Add lintOnSave:false to the file.