# Component name "Temp" should always be multi-word vue/multi-word-component-names

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, eslint

I am new In Vue.js Technology. I am getting an error while running my Vue application. Don't know where I am wrong, please try to fix my error.

This is the Temp File where I am getting an Error.

> Temp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Ashish</h1>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Temp",
};
</script>
```

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <!-- <HomeComp msg="Hello Harshal"/> -->
  <!-- <ForLoop/> -->
  <Temp/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
// import HomeComp from './components/HomeComp.vue';
// import ForLoop from './components/ForLoop.vue';
import Temp from './components/Temp.vue';


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    // HomeComp,
    // ForLoop
    // Demo,
    Temp
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your linter just tells you, that your component name should be a multi word like **MyTemp** instead of just **Temp**.

You could rename the component or disable the linting rule.

Comment: How does one do that in a vue app?

Comment: Right click the file name and rename it to whatever you'd like.

Comment: Are you seriously supposed to add meaningless words to a component that best fits as a single word?  That seems like a horrible rule to be the default.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat It's like that because in the future default HTML tags may be created that can conflict with how you used components in your code. But it's kinda pointless, instead just force developers to have components in PascalCase. That way Vue knows if a tag has a capital letter, it's 100% a component. Also since it's declared in the 'components' object anyway, I don't know if this rule should really exist, just overwrite the potential HTML tag and that's all.

Comment: Single word components can have wrong highlighting in IDEs. And if component name matches native HTML tag, autocomplete will suggest wrong attributes and show wrong errors about missing attributes. And it's just a big problem to differ native tag from kebab-cased single word component

Answer (score 59):

Add this to the "rules"-section at eslintrc.js if you don't want to change component names:

```
'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
```

(Taken from the response of @lifecoder above, but can't add it as a comment due to my reputation)

Comment: My rules were listed under "eslintConfig" in `package.json`, and I had to *restart* VS Code for the change to take effect

Comment: updated `package.json` and still getting the error... don't have a `eslintrc.js` file, so I don't know where this should set...

Comment: @monkut Just create it in the project's root folder (the folder where .gitignore, README.md are located).

Answer (score 25):

Add `"rules": {"vue/multi-word-component-names": "off"}` to eslintConfig in package.json

Comment: This had no impact.

Answer (score 7):

There are several things you can do to help:

1. To name two floods
2. That you can add this code to your project:

```
{
   "vue/multi-word-component-names": ["error", {
      "ignores": []
   }]
}
```

Be sure to look at the full document on [this site](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html).

Comment: If you want to disable the rule, better specify it as off:

```
'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
```

Comment: what is the name of file where i have to update above json?

Comment: Hello, where do I add these lines specifically?

Comment: @LeninZapata You can add this code on ```.eslintrc.js```. also you can check below link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570973/how-to-disable-vue-multi-word-component-names-eslint-rule-for-just-one-vue-file

Answer (score 1):

So I also encounter the same error, All you have to do is change the name of the component from Temp to MyTemp or any other two word combination.

Here, you can also see and take the idea from the vue/multi-word-component-names Documentation, They explained things very clearly and is very helpful :-

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to change the name of the Component. Temp to MyTemp.

So replace every where you have Temp to MyTemp

And try by renaming the declaring part like this instead of MyTemp

```
<my-temp />
```

Comment: Why would you use kebab-case and how does it help here? Kebab case is the cause that this pointless rule exists, and it's only useful if you're not using SFC.

Comment: Vue3 reccomends using PascalCase in Single File Components

Answer (score 1):

In `<script setup>` syntax the component name is inferred from the file name which should be written in PascalCase format like

```
TempComp.vue
```

or in kebab-case format :

```
temp-comp.vue
```

other format like `tempComp` or `temp-Comp` are accepted but they look bad

for more details please check [rule-details](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html#rule-details)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a multiple word name, like "MyCounters", not only "Counter".

```
export default {
  name: "MeusContadores",
  components: {
    "app-contador": MeuContador,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to vue.config.js file

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
  module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  // Add this line of code to disable lintOnSave
  lintOnSave: false
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is potentially harmful (to the workflow). It's like disabling ESLint but not completely. Better just disable the rule. Use @Joshua's answer only after reading [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave)

Comment: Yeah this just disables linting until you explicitly lint the project. Don't follow this answer

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
Export default {
Name : '( this name )'
```

This name should be multi-word
For example

```
(mytepm)
(MyTemp)
```