# Disable all eslint rules from a plugin for a file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, security, eslint

I have two files which are siblings.

- index.js
- index.test.js

First is for source, second is the unit tests for first file.

I have a lot of eslint rules to check my sources. And I use some plugins to enhance thoses checks. Especially [security-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-security).

It makes sense to check security into source code, but i don't mind for tests files. How can i disable into tests files only security rules?

I already have tried those but it's not working:

```
/* eslint-disable security */
/* eslint-disable security/* */
```

Any idea is welcomed. I just want to keep source and test files as siblings

Comment: You can use [`overrides`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file/65069069#65069069) to ignore rules for your `xxx.test.js` files, but AFAIK you can't ignore a whole plugin and need to disable all the rules specifically.

Comment: It seems that you're true sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a found a trick. I just run eslint twice. One time for "normal" sources with tests excluded, and a second time with another configuration file without security plugin declared inside only for tests.
Not the smartest way but does the job.