# Assignment to function parameter 'value' no-param-reassign

Tags: reactjs, typescript-eslint, reassign

I am trying to get rid off the `no-param-reassign` error from the following code.

```
const changeHandler = ({ key, ref, value }): void => {
const properties = array.find((e) => e.key === key && e.color);
if (properties) {
  properties.color = value.hex; <<<<< this line throwing error. 
  saveAll();
}
```

};

Tried with adding the followings:

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */

my code ....
/* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */

 // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
```

Nothing has worked. Also tried creating a new variable and assign to it. Still didn't work. I can't commit code due to that error.

I need to update this (`properties.color`) array element with function parameter value.

Comment: See if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637900/13262332

Comment: Unfortunately I tried most of the suggestion from the post you suggested. But nothing worked.