# react/prop-types eslint error in typescript react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am trying to set up a `typescript-react-eslint` project and can't get past eslint error for this boilerplate component:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface ButtonProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  onClick?: (e: any) => void,
}

const styles = {
  border: "1px solid #eee",
  borderRadius: 3,
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  cursor: "pointer",
  fontSize: 15,
  padding: "3px 10px",
  margin: 10
};

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = props => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick} style={styles} type="button">
    {props.children}
  </button>
);

Button.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  onClick: () => {}
};
export default Button;
```

The error is:

```
  19:26  error  'onClick' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
  20:12  error  'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

It seems like it is complaining about interface for html `<button>` is not defined?
Otherwise it might be the `Button` component itself but should it not get type information from `<ButtonProps>` interface I pass there?

I tried explicitly setting `children` and `onClick` like this:

```
Button.propTypes = {
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  onClick?: (e: any) => void
};
```

it bypasses the eslint error but the component itself stops working.
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. This is my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "pragma": "React",
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Use default values inside arguments `<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick: () => {}, children: null }) => (`

Comment: You don't need to define `children` in `ButtonProps` as `React.FunctionComponent<T>` already defines it as: `children?: ReactNode`. Also, you can use `React.FC` instead of the very verbose `React.FunctionComponent`

Comment: If I don't define children in `ButtonProps`, nothing changes: error still complains about both `children` and `onClick`. It seems like the interface is being ignored in `const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = props => ...`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the component as:

```
const Button = ({ children, onClick }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick} style={styles} type="button">
    {children}
  </button>;
};
```

The `: React.FC<ButtonProps>` part was ignored by eslint so I decided to provide prop types in a more straightforward way

Answer (score 21):

This rule doesn't make sense with TypeScript because you already is checking types.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948970/how-to-disable-eslint-react-prop-types-rule-in-a-file) you found a simple way to disable this rule, just add in your eslint configuration:

```json
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': 0
  }
```

to be more readable you can use "off" instead "0".

Answer (score 6):

`eslint-plugin-react@^7.25.0` appears to have [resolved](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/3051) the issue for those using `React.FC<IProps>` with `react/prop-types` validation rule.

So instead of

```
const Example: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => ...
```

This now works without warnings after the update

```
const Example: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => ...
```

Comment: if we use a generic type for components, we can't use React.FC, and when passing props explicitly like `(props: Props) => `, the warning will be shown again

Answer (score 3):

**More info to your answer..**

Firstly both ways are correct for declaring types, But React.FC has some added benefits.
https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/blob/master/README.md#function-components

[image]

And in your scenario you may be using eslint-react-plugin which has recommended rules 'plugin:react/recommended' for eslint ,
Rule to check proptypes is one among them, check typescript example.
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md

**So react/prop-types rule will conflict with TS Interfaces, which is why it shows that error, once you add : ButtonProps, we don't have to provide React.FC**

Comment: FYI that page you linked to has been updated to say "the general consensus today is that React.FunctionComponent (or the shorthand React.FC) is discouraged"

Answer (score 0):

importing React solved my problem

```
import React from 'react';
```