# React function parameters - Failed prop type: expected `boolean`

Tags: reactjs, function, types, parameters, prop

I'm trying to call a Modal I made in another class. I simply want to pass a boolean parameter to open or close it.

Calling the modal:

```
<CourseModal show={true} />
```

Modal function:

```
export default function CourseModal(show) {
  return (
    <Modal open={show}>
        <ModalContent />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:

[image]

Why does this happen? It says it expects a boolean, but it clearly is? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using typescript for your project?

Comment: @Captain328 No just javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you pass the `props` object itself, you just named it `show`.

```
export default function CourseModal({ show }) {
  return (
    <Modal open={show}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  );
}

// You called it show instead of props
export default function CourseModal(props) {
  return (
    <Modal open={props.show}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  );
}

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const CourseModal = ({ show }) => {
  return (
    <Modal open={show}>
      ...
    </Modal>
  );
};

CourseModal.propTypes = {
  show: PropTypes.bool;
}

export default CourseModal;
```

Also, in JSX you don't have to pass `true` boolean, you can write:

```
// Same as show={true}
<CourseModal show />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly I'm still stuck with an error using your solution. https://i.gyazo.com/d40c3dba6ce075e1744fbefa7ee0194a.png

Comment: Same problem: https://i.gyazo.com/9c3985bd207b45b2ec4fd7b41e7027df.png

Comment: Its a warning, the code should work... Do you have `prop-types` installed?... I'll add it to an answer in case you do

Comment: See what prop-types means: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Comment: Woops, you're right it works. Thanks. Can I just ignore the warning then?

Comment: You can, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948970/how-to-disable-eslint-react-prop-types-rule-in-a-file

Comment: Thank you. Marked your solution as answer.