# React PropTypes, 'prop.attr' is missing in prop validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-props

I am seeing a linting react/prop-type error stating that the children in an array as well as the parent value are missing from prop validation. When I add the types I still get the error. I am not sure what I am missing here, here is my current code:

```
type Props = {
  book: {
    name: string,
    description: any,
  },
};

type State = {};

export default class Book extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
    render() {
        const {
          name,
          description,
        } = this.props.book;
        
        return (
        <BookModal
          name={name}
          description={description} 
        />
    );
  }
}
```

As always thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

Thats a warning for [`PropTypes` validation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Book.propTypes = {
  // or book: PropTypes.object 
  book: PropTypes.shape({
    color: PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: PropTypes.number,
  }),
};
```

See [PropTypes in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/7882470), and [how to disable proptypes linting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425808/7882470) (if you decide that you don't need it).

Comment: For some reason this reads out as an unexpected token error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using prop-types you could try:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';    
type Props = {
     book: PropTypes.shape({
       color: PropTypes.string,
       fontSize: PropTypes.number
     })
}
```

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes